# Difference between " / " and " ./ " in laravel routing?

Tags: laravel

i have seen lots of online tutorials using "/" simple for listing its current path, for example:

Example: home page route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');

});
```

which is working, but when changes '/' to './' it shows pages not found.

my local homepage URL is: http://localhost:8888/Todo/public/

Can anyone tell me what's the difference of using '/' and './' ?

Comment: `'/'` is correct but    ` './' `, As a route, is not correct and does not mean, and can be used in addressing files and directories.

Comment: `./` is not valid, that's why not found

Comment: is that "./" refers to current file or directory only? so "./" is never valid in URLs am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

./ is not working because it's a wrong value for route, ./ is used for addressing files, and dot in path means current directory